# How do I redirect the user after a successful login on firebase?

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase

I just started a new project and I'm working on auth. I am able to login the users using email, google or github. But how do I redirect them to another page on a successful login:
Here is the code below:

```
var config = {
apiKey: "asdfasdfasdf",
authDomain: "asdfasdfasdf",
databaseURL: "asdfasdfasdf",
storageBucket: "asdfasdfasdf",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//The stuff
var logine = document.getElementById("logine");
var reggy = document.getElementById("reggy");
var usr = document.getElementById("usr");
var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd");
var reset = document.getElementById("forgot");
var google = document.getElementById("google");
var logout = document.getElementById("logout");
var github = document.getElementById("github");

//Login event
function loginEvent(){
//Retreive the email and dat pwd
var email = usr.value;
var password = pwd.value;
var auth = firebase.auth();
//User signs in
var promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).catch(function(error){
//Handle any errors here
var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;

  if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password'){
    alert('Get the password right');
  } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
});
promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
if (email.length < 12){
  document.getElementById("bademail").classList.remove("hide");

}
if(password.length < 6){
  document.getElementById("bademail").classList.remove("hide");
}
}

//Register event
function registerEvent(){
    var email = usr.value;
var password = pwd.value;
var auth = firebase.auth();

//User signs in

// TODO: Check for email 
var promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error){
  //Handle any errors here
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;

  if(errorCode === 'auth/weak-password'){
    alert('All passwords are must be 6 characters or more')
  } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }

  });
  promise
  .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  if (email.length < 12){
  document.getElementById("bademail").classList.remove("hide");
  }

  }
function logoutEvent(){
firebase.auth().signOut();
}
//Signing in with Google
function googleAuth(){
 //Google Auth
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
// This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
var token = result.credential.accessToken;
// The signed-in user info.
var user = result.user;
// ...
}).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;
// The email of the user's account used.
var email = error.email;
// The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
var credential = error.credential;
// ...
});
}
//Signing in with github
function githubAuth(){
var provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
// This gives you a GitHub Access Token. You can use it to access the GitHub API.
var token = result.credential.accessToken;
// The signed-in user info.
var user = result.user;
// ...
}).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;
// The email of the user's account used.
var email = error.email;
// The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
var credential = error.credential;
// ...
});

}
//Password reset email
function sendPasswordReset() {
  var email = document.getElementById('usr').value;
  // [START sendpasswordemail]
  firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(function() {
    // Password Reset Email Sent!
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    alert('We sent the email so check tu inbox');
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    if (errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email') {
      alert(errorMessage);
    } else if (errorCode == 'auth/user-not-found') {
      alert(errorMessage);
    }
    console.log(error);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    });
    // [END sendpasswordemail];
    }

  //Realtime listener
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
  if(firebaseUser){
  console.log(firebaseUser);
  document.getElementById("logout").classList.remove('hide');
  window.location("index.html");
      }else{
  console.log("GET OUT KID");
  document.getElementById("logout").classList.add('hide');
        reset.addEventListener('click', sendPasswordReset, false);
        google.addEventListener('click', googleAuth, false);
        logine.addEventListener('click', loginEvent, false);
        reggy.addEventListener('click', registerEvent, false);
        logout.addEventListener('click', logoutEvent, false);
        github.addEventListener('click', githubAuth, false);
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To handle login and logout, always use `onAuthStateChanged()`

```
//Handle Account Status
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    window.location = 'home.html';
  }
});
```

The moment someone logins, `user` will be populated with user details and you can use it to redirect to another page.